# Redirect user to the login page after SP's session timeout

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have a Grails application with Spring SAML and WSO2 IS as IdP.

After session timeout UI refreshes the page and user is redirected to the login page. It is done to protect sensitive information from seeing by other people, in case the user leaves the page opened for a long time.

But after we implemented SSO, this mechanism doesn't work anymore - after session timeout page is reloaded and IDP reauthenticates it automatically.

As I understand, there are two sessions: IdP's and SP's. And when SP's session is invalidated, IDP's is still alive.

Is it possible to redirect user to SSO login page after session timeout? 
Are there some best practices how to handle session timeout using SSO?

Comment: What is the identity server version you are using? Did you created SP at identity server using the Identity Server management console?

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna I'm using V4.6.0. Yes, SP was registered on "Register New Service Provider" page using IS managment console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's imposible to synchronize sessions using SSO, so I decided to set the same value for SP session and IdP session. It's not perfect solution, but at least the behavior is similar to expected

Answer (score 1):

In order for this scenario to work your SP must issue a Logout request. Spring SAML supports Single and Local logouts. In case of the Local logout neither of the other SP sessions are affected nor IDP, just the current SP's session is logged out. In the Single Logout case IDP instructs all SPs to terminate the session and then IDP session is also terminated. In either case there must be a request coming from your SP as the session times out.

More information is available here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-logout

Comment: but what if there will be several SP? isn't strange the fact that after session timeout the user is not authenticated, and should be redirected to the SSO login page, but in the other SPs this user is authenticated? Does't this break the idea of SSO?

Comment: @TarasKohut Have a look at response.assertion.authnStatement.sessionNotOnOfAfter, but this is all down to your SP implementation. From the SP's perspective you might need to specifically tell IdP to perform logout. If this is a Global logout then IdP will notify the other SPs that they need to terminate their session as well.

Comment: I tried your solution, but actually after SP requests local logout user is redirected to the login page, and because SSO session is alive, SP is reauthenticated. It seems like this is impossible to be redirected to the login page without auto-login until global session exists. Or am I missing something?